# Nginx Configuration - Cache headers on certain paths

Tags: nginx

From my understanding of nginx docs, locations can't be nested (or rather if they are the effects aren't inheritable) and `proxy_pass` can't belong at the `server {}` level. So my configuration at the moment is like this, I know I can alleviate some by using filepaths but let's pretend I want different cache headers on different paths whilst using `proxy_pass`. Presumably there is a better way to write this without the repition:

```
server {
  listen  80;
  server_name salessystem.acmecorp.com;

  location /extjs/ {
    ## proxy_buffers 128 256k;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5400/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    add_header 'X-UA-Compatible' 'IE=Edge;chrome=1';
    expires max;
    gzip  on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 7;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/html text/css text/pdf application/json application/x-javascript text/javascript;
    access_log off;
    break;
  }

  location / {
    ## proxy_buffers 128 256k;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5400/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    add_header 'X-UA-Compatible' 'IE=Edge;chrome=1';
    expires epoch;
    gzip  on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 7;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/html text/css text/pdf application/json application/x-javascript text/javascript;
    access_log off;
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: can the common gzip options be included in the server block instead of in each location block? is that what you are asking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think of the following for your nginx configuration :

- since it is just the expires header that differs for your two different locations, although both matching the proxy to the same
  server.
- try putting both the locations in the single block
- based on the query string, (or location match string) set a different
  expires header

tag.

```
server {
  listen  80;
  server_name salessystem.acmecorp.com;

  location ~* (/extjs/|/) {
    ## proxy_buffers 128 256k;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5400/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    add_header 'X-UA-Compatible' 'IE=Edge;chrome=1';
    expires max;
      if ($query_string ~ \/extjs\/) {
      expires epoch;
      }
    gzip  on;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_comp_level 7;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_types text/html text/css text/pdf application/json application/x-javascript text/javascript;
    access_log off;
    break;
  }

}
```

Please however test according to your needs, especially near the regex matches at `location`  and `query_string` value matching.

However it is not clear, why would you want to  `extjs` to be served out of a proxied server (seems like a dynamic app server), since they are just plain text files if my assumption is right. The requests pertaining to `extjs` need not go through the proxy or app logic system just incase while they can be served independently through the filesystem. I think of keeping it in its seperate location itself, and have the unique gzip/expires directives unique to it in its own location block while the other common directives can be held in the server block itself.

For example:

```
server {
   ...
   common gzip directives
   common header setters
   common expires setters
   ...
   location / {
     proxy to backend app server
     settings unique to / location
     ..
   }
   location /extjs {
     settings unique to /extjs location
     expires header reset
     ...
   }
}
```

Comment: @nginxtest what did you do? I am interested in your find outs and configuration details.. thanks.

Comment: Using `if` here is not recommended; see http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil for additional details. `map` would be a more appropriate directive to use.